# Array iteration in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Array: {3412124539: 1, 3412124540: 1, 3412124577: 2, 3412124590: 1, 3412124602: 1, 3412124605: 1, 3412124607: 1, 3412124617: 1, 3412124629: 1, 3412124630: 1, 4709502367: 1, 4709502349: 1, 4709502326: 1, 4708510268: 1, 4708510060: 1, …}
```

I want to search for `3412124577`.
If the value is `2`
Then return.

How should I do that. Also when I tried iterating `Array[30]`. It gives me error.
How should I do search.

Comment: is it array or object?

Comment: this is not array this is object

Comment: show the code ...

Comment: I used  _UNIQUEARRAY = _.countBy(all, "wellUid");

Comment: @RahulJain Then just do `_UNIQUEARRAY[3412124577]`?

Comment: _UNIQUEARRAY = _.countBy(all, "wellUid");   --> I used this lodash function to get the occurance of wellUid in object all. Mentioned lodash function returns an array

Comment: `_.countBy` returns an object, not an array.

Comment: then it should allow me to iterate viaindex. But it complains.
I even tried _UNIQUEARRAY[3412124577]. Still it complains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know you are talking about arrays in your post but your "array" you give to us is actually an object. Major shocker, I know... Notice the array [ ] vs object { } brackets.

But this isn't actually a bad thing in your case. You won't need to loop over all items in an array at all!! Let me show you.

You can access the keys of the object by array notation in javascript. (still following?) The basic way to do that is:

```
object['key']           //accessing by array notation
```

or

```
object.key              //accesing by dot notation
```

And since you're talking about returning, I'm presuming your talking about functions. Take a look at the following search function using a check on the object named collection with array notation

```js
var collection = {3412124539: 1, 3412124540: 1, 3412124577: 2, 3412124590: 1, 3412124602: 1, 3412124605: 1, 3412124607: 1, 3412124617: 1, 3412124629: 1, 3412124630: 1, 4709502367: 1, 4709502349: 1, 4709502326: 1, 4708510268: 1, 4708510060: 1}

function search(inWhat, forWhat, equalsWhat){
  if(inWhat[forWhat] == equalsWhat)
    return 'returned cause '+forWhat+' is '+equalsWhat;
}

var returnValue = search(collection, 3412124577, 2);

// ---- outputting the returnValue here
document.write(returnValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it might work.

```
$.each(yourVariableHere, function( index, value ) {
    if(index == 2){
         console.log("I found it.");
    }
});
```